# Как закрашивать программно imageView?

Tags: android

Есть макет(трафарет) в виде сердца.

Из сервера получаю список разных данных в том числе о цвете.
Можно ли используя один этот трафарет, закрасить сердце в зависимости от полученных данных?

Как сделать не знаю. Единственное что в голове у меня появляется мысль это сделать 100 таких картинок разных цветов...Но это глупо. Есть обходной путь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял,то тебе нужно это:

```
 imageView.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255)); //к примеру белый цвет
```

Comment: Это типо если есть картинка зеленная. с белыми рамками. То при указании этого метода зеленный перекрасится в  беллый?

Comment: Допусти есть PNG сердца красного цвета без фона, при использовании этого метода сердце будет отображаться белым